# Writing a Python script for Telegram mention bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've installed latest version Python in my Windows 8.1 32 bit. I have created a Telegram bot. I've also written a script for my bot. I've installed pip, Telegram, Python Telegram bot and others which are needed to run my telegram bot.

Here's the code I've written for my Telegram bot:

```
import logging
from telegram import Update

# from telegram.update import Update

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, CallbackContext, Filters


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

TOKEN = 'I removed it for now'

# Initialize the Updater
updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# Command handler
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text("Hello! I am your mention bot. Use @everyone to mention all members.")

start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

# Mention handler
def handle_mentions(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    message_text = update.message.text
    if "@everyone" in message_text:
        chat_id = update.message.chat_id
        
        # Get the list of all members in the group
        all_members = context.bot.get_chat_members(chat_id)
        
        # Prepare the mention message
        mention_message = " ".join([f"@{member.user.username}" for member in all_members if member.user.username])
        if mention_message:
            mention_message = f"Mentioning all members: {mention_message}"
        else:
            mention_message = "No active members to mention."
        
        # Send the mention message
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id, mention_message, reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id)

mention_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, handle_mentions)
dispatcher.add_handler(mention_handler)

# Start the bot
updater.start_polling()

# Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C
updater.idle()
```

Whenever I try to run these script saved as mention_bot.py by commanding `cd c:\python\bot\python mention_bot.py`, it always shows me this error:

```
C:\Python\bot>python mention_bot.py Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\bot\mention_bot.py", line 2, in <module>
from telegram import Update
ImportError: cannot import name 'Update' from 'telegram' (C:\Python\Lib\site-pa kages\telegram\_____init__.py>
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Did you install the pypi package python-telegram-bot?  Or something else?  I'd remove whatever telegram package you have in site-packages, and install a fresh copy of python-telegram-bot, which has the Update objects you require.

Comment: I've installed pip install python-telegram-bot

Answer (score 0):

> I've installed telegram

This is the problem. Run `pip uninstall telegram` to uninstall the [telegram library](https://pypi.org/project/telegram/) and then run pip install python-telegram-bot again.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: I've completely uninstalled the whole python and its all folders from my windows and reinstall it. Then I've just put pip install python-telegram-bot and then try to run my saved mention_bot.py but it shows that filters error